# Resize TextArea in extended skin

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, I'm trying to make an extension of TextArea, such that if there is an additionally specified String parameter at the bottom of TextArea, this text is displayed as a hint.

This was very easily implemented on a separate Pane, when he added a listener to the property and just added a Label below.

I tried to do it in a more regular way: I created classes that extend TextArea and TextAreaSkin, and added the StringProperty "hint" to the TextArea class. Added a listener to this property in TextAreaSkin:

```
public TextValueSkin(final TextValue control) {
    super(control);
    this.textValue = control;
    registerChangeListener(textValue.hintProperty(), e -> {
        updateHint();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            control.requestLayout();
            if (control.getParent() != null) {
                control.getParent().requestLayout();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And override method layoutChildren (double x, double y, double w, double h):

```
protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
    final double bottomHeight = lblHint == null ? 0.0 : snapSizeY(lblHint.prefHeight(w));
    double textHeight = h - snapSizeY(bottomHeight);
    super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, textHeight);
    if (lblHint != null) {
        lblHint.resizeRelocate(x, textHeight, w, bottomHeight);
    }
}
```

Thus, I got the following type of TextArea with a hint:
[enter image description here] [image: 1]

That is, the ScrollPane and the text content took on a new size (minus the Label height), the light border (related to the ContentView) took on a new size, but the white background itself and the bright border remained the same size.

Please help me to adjust to reduce the height of this background and the border.

Full demo below. The my question is visible when TextValue is focused (please see attached screenshot). The hint is inside a bright border and against a white background of editable text, although it does not apply to it in any way.

Main.class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextValue textValue = new TextValue();
        textValue.setText("Text");
        Scene scene = new Scene(textValue);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Platform.runLater(() -> textValue.setHint("HINT"));
    }
}
```

TextValue.class:

```
public class TextValue extends TextArea {

    private StringProperty hint = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "hint");

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty hintProperty() {
        return hint;
    }

    public void setHint(String hint) {
        this.hint.set(hint);
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new TextValueSkin(this);
    }
}
```

TextValueSkin.class:

```
public class TextValueSkin extends TextAreaSkin {

    final private TextValue textValue;
    private Label lblHint;

    public TextValueSkin(TextValue control) {
        super(control);
        this.textValue = control;
        registerChangeListener(textValue.hintProperty(), e -> {
            updateHint();
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                control.requestLayout();
                if (control.getParent() != null) {
                    control.getParent().requestLayout();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private void updateHint() {
        getChildren().remove(lblHint);
        String hint = textValue.hintProperty().get();
        if (hint != null && !hint.isEmpty()) {
            lblHint = new Label(hint);
            lblHint.getStyleClass().add("hint");
            lblHint.setManaged(false);
            getChildren().add(lblHint);
        } else {
            lblHint = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        final double bottomHeight = lblHint == null ? 0.0 : snapSizeY(lblHint.prefHeight(w));
        double textHeight = h - snapSizeY(bottomHeight);
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, textHeight);
        if (lblHint != null) {
            lblHint.resizeRelocate(x, textHeight, w, bottomHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra I have added a complete demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is behavior extends from default style of TextArea. It's required for highlighting border around scroll bar. I rewrote the default style so that the highlighted border refers to the ScrollPane and not to TextArea.

CSS:

```
.vbox-demo {
    -fx-padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    -fx-spacing: 1em;
}

.text-value {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-cursor: default;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
.text-value:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.text-value .scroll-pane:disabled {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.text-value .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
}
.text-value:focused .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 4, 0;
}
.text-value > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 1 0 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 2 2;
}
.text-value > .scroll-pane > .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 2 2 0;
}
.text-value > .scroll-pane > .corner {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 2 0;
}
.text-value .content {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0.583em 0.25em 0.583em; /* 3 7 3 7 */
    -fx-cursor: text;
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 4px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -8%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
}
.text-value:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 2, 1, 0;
}
.text-value > .hint {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0 0 0;
}
```

Final TextValue.class:

```
public class TextValue extends TextArea {

    public TextValue() {
        getStyleClass().add("text-value");
    }

    private StringProperty hint = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "hint");

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty hintProperty() {
        return hint;
    }

    public void setHint(String hint) {
        this.hint.set(hint);
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new TextValueSkin(this);
    }
}
```

Final TextValueSkin.class:

```
public class TextValueSkin extends TextAreaSkin {

    final private TextValue textValue;
    private Label lblHint;

    public TextValueSkin(final TextValue control) {
        super(control);
        this.textValue = control;
        registerChangeListener(textValue.hintProperty(), e -> updateHint());
    }

    private void updateHint() {
        getChildren().remove(lblHint);
        String hint = textValue.hintProperty().get();
        if (hint != null && !hint.isEmpty()) {
            lblHint = new Label(hint);
            lblHint.getStyleClass().add("hint");
            lblHint.setManaged(false);
            getChildren().add(lblHint);
        } else {
            lblHint = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        final double bottomHeight = lblHint == null ? 0.0 : snapSizeY(lblHint.prefHeight(w));
        final double textHeight = h - snapSizeY(bottomHeight);
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, textHeight);
        if (lblHint != null) {
            lblHint.resizeRelocate(x, textHeight, w, bottomHeight);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double w, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        final double prefHeight = super.computePrefHeight(w, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
        final double addHeight = lblHint == null ? 0.0 : snapSizeY(lblHint.prefHeight(w));
        return prefHeight + addHeight;
}

    @Override
    protected double computeMinHeight(double w, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        final double minHeight = super.computeMinHeight(w, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
        final double addHeight = lblHint == null ? 0.0 : snapSizeY(lblHint.minHeight(w));
        return minHeight + addHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMaxHeight(double w, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        final double maxHeight = super.computeMaxHeight(w, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
        final double addHeight = lblHint == null ? 0.0 : snapSizeY(lblHint.maxHeight(w));
        return maxHeight + addHeight;
    }
}
```

Final demo Main.class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextValue textValue = new TextValue();
        textValue.setText("Text");
        TextField tf = new TextField("");
        VBox vBox = new VBox(textValue, tf);
        vBox.getStyleClass().add("vbox-demo");
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        textValue.setHint("HINT");
    }
}
```